# Single Word City name like "California" shows result but double word "New York" doesn't

Tags: javascript, php, openweathermap, weather

This is a PHP & JS based web page that represents a weather website. When I enter any string that contains one word, whether it is a valid city name or not, it provides a result. But when I input in the form any double word string it shows nothing. However if I manually input the city name like `New York` in the api link url it shows all the JSON data correctly.

The following is my code:

```
<?php
    $status = "";
    $msg = "";
    $city = "";
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $city = $_POST['city'];
       $url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=92b2d5275d8ce6c94cd0a72ffc7bd208";
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       $result = json_decode($result, true);
           if ($result['cod'] == 200) {
          $status = "yes";
       } else {
          $msg = $result['message'];
       }
    }
?>

<html lang="en" class=" -webkit-">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weather</title>
    <style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One);
    @import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/weather-icons/2.0.9/css/weather-icons.min.css);

    body {
        background-image: url("weather.png");
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        font-family: Poiret One;
        background-blend-mode: screen;
    }

    .widget {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        display: flex;
        height: 300px;
        width: 600px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 27px 55px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 17px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .widget .weatherIcon {
        flex: 1 100%;
        height: 60%;
        border-top-left-radius: 20px;
        border-top-right-radius: 20px;
        background: #FAFAFA;
        font-family: weathericons;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .widget .weatherIcon i {
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .widget .weatherInfo {
        flex: 0 0 70%;
        height: 40%;
        background: darkslategray;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        color: white;
    }

    .widget .weatherInfo .temperature {
        flex: 0 0 40%;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 65px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .widget .weatherInfo .description {
        flex: 0 60%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }

    .widget .weatherInfo .description .weatherCondition {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 35px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }

    .widget .weatherInfo .description .place {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .widget .date {
        flex: 0 0 30%;
        height: 40%;
        background: #70C1B3;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 800;
    }

    p {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0%;
        right: 2%;
    }

    p a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #E4D6A7;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .form {
        position: absolute;
        top: 42%;
        left: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: start;
        height: 300px;
        width: 600px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .text {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
        box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
    }


    .conmain {
        margin-right: 45px;
    }

    button {
        padding: 9px;
        width: 30%;
        border: unset;
        border-radius: 15px;
        color: #212121;
        z-index: 1;
        background: #e8e8e8;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 1000;
        font-size: 17px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
        box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
        transition: all 250ms;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    button::before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background-color: darkslategray;
        z-index: -1;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
        box-shadow: 4px 8px 19px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
        transition: all 250ms
    }

    button:hover {
        color: #e8e8e8;
    }

    button:hover::before {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #getLocation {
        width: 40%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <p><?php
         var_dump($ch)
         ?></p><br>
        <p><?php
         var_dump($result)
         ?></p><br>

        <p><?php var_dump($status)?></p>
        <form style="width:100%;" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Enter country or city name" name="city"
                value="<?php echo $city ?>" />
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="submit">submit</button>
            <?php echo $msg ?>
        </form>
        <button id="getLocation">My Location</button>

    </div>

    <?php if ($status == "yes") { ?>
    <article class="widget">
        <div class="weatherIcon">
            <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/<?php echo $result['weather'][0]['icon'] ?>@4x.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="weatherInfo">
            <div class="temperature">
                <span><?php echo round($result['main']['temp'] - 273.15) ?>°</span>
            </div>
            <div class="description conmain">
                <div class="weatherCondition"><?php echo $result['weather'][0]['main'] ?></div>
                <div class="place"><?php echo $result['name'] ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <div class="weatherCondition">Wind</div>
                <div class="place"><?php echo $result['wind']['speed'] ?> M/H</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
            <?php echo date('d M', $result['dt']) ?>

        </div>
    </article>
    <?php } ?>

    <script>
    const getLocationButton = document.getElementById("getLocation");
    getLocationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                // Use the latitude and longitude to fetch the location data
                fetchLocationData(latitude, longitude);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser.");
        }
    });

    function fetchLocationData(latitude, longitude) {
        const locationUrl = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;
        fetch(locationUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const city = data.address.city || data.address.town || data.address.village;
                if (city) {
                    document.querySelector('input[name="city"]').value = city;
                    // Auto-submit the form by simulating a click on the submit button
                    document.querySelector('[name="submit"]').click();
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Error fetching location data:", error);
            });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm expecting to get results no matter how many words I input in the form and would really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: When you build the URL with the "city" value, you have to properly encode the value so that the URL syntax is valid.

Comment: exactly what is the value of `$city` ... it shouldn't have a space in it - by the way, you should not expose your API key like that ... someone could abuse it - I'd "retire" that key from openweathermap and get a new one

Comment: Please refer to following documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you should `URL-encode` the city name before appending it to the API URL. You can use the PHP function `urlencode()` for this purpose. Hope the following helps

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $city = urlencode($_POST['city']); // URL-encode the city name
   $url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=$city&appid=92b2d5275d8ce6c94cd0a72ffc7bd208";
   $ch = curl_init();
```